# Subsetting by number of observations per hour in R

Tags: r, count, time-series, subset

I have radiotracking data spanning 6 weeks which is less reliable when the number of detections (i.e. observations) are low in a given time period. Therefore, I would like to subset my data frame so any hour with less than 10 detections is excluded from my data. As seen in the dataframe below, one row of 'Power' corresponds to one detection.

```
     DateTime               Power

>  1. 2018-05-21 20:56:04    30
>  2. 2018-05-21 20:56:07    20
>  3. 2018-05-21 20:56:44    35
>  4. 2018-05-21 20:56:47    37
>  5. 2018-05-21 20:57:48    26
>  6. 2018-05-21 21:32:36    35
```

I understand this probably involves doing some kind of count by hour first, which I think I have achieved using the code below (which then produced the dataframe beneath) but I'm unsure as to how I now subset my initial data frame with these counts.

```
Tag201 %>% 
    count(Date1 = as.Date(DateTime), Hour = hour(DateTime)) %>%
    group_by(Date1) %>% 
    complete(Date1, Hour = min(Hour):24, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    arrange(Date1, Hour)

 Date1       Hour     n
  <date>     <int> <dbl>
1 2018-05-19     0   402
2 2018-05-19     1     4
3 2018-05-19     2   501
4 2018-05-19     3   858
5 2018-05-19     4   192
6 2018-05-19     5    19
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I managed to do this with the below code:

```
Tag201 <- Tag201 %>%
  group_by(Date=floor_date(DateTime, "1 hour")) %>%
  mutate(c1=length(Power))

tt <- table(Tag201$c1)
Tag201 <- subset(Tag201, c1 %in% names(tt[tt >10]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a dput version of your data so we can test out our answers to your question. I think you can do something like this:

```
Tag201 %>% 
    mutate(Date1 = as.Date(DateTime) %>%
    mutate(Hour = hour(DateTime) %>%
    group_by(Date1, Hour) %>%
    mutate(n = n() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(Date1) %>% 
    complete(Date1, Hour = min(Hour):24, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(Date1, Hour) %>%
    filter(n > 10)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response and sorry for not including a dput version in my data - it was my first question! Your code worked, thank you. I had actually managed to successfully do it before I got your response - I included my way of doing it in the edit. Thanks again.